# How can something be created from fire?

Tags: quran, tafseer, shaitan

Al-A'raf 7:12
قَالَ مَا مَنَعَكَ أَلَّا تَسْجُدَ إِذْ أَمَرْتُكَۖ قَالَ أَنَا۠ خَيْرٌ مِّنْهُ خَلَقْتَنِى مِن نَّارٍ وَخَلَقْتَهُۥ مِن طِينٍ
English - Sahih International

> [Allāh] said, "What prevented you from prostrating when I commanded
> you?" [Satan] said, "I am better than him. You created me from fire
> and created him from clay [i.e., earth]."

How can something be created from fire? Fire is not matter. Fire is a result of oxidation manifested in heat and light. Fire can't exist unless you burn something, so what does it mean to be made from fire?

I could grasp it if it was by or with fire, but understanding how something can be made **from** fire is difficult for me.

Comment: "How can something be created from matter? Matter is not fire." -- Satan, probably.

Comment: @goldPseudo added more details

Comment: How can anything be created from anything? If you were to think of it physically, how clay make any difference.

Comment: @lr0 Clay is matter, it can be shaped to make objects/things. On the other hand fire is a result of oxidation manifested in heat and light. Fire can't exist unless you burn something and it will only exist as long as the said thing is burning. In other words, fire is completely dependent on fuel for its existence and is a sensory manifestation of the oxidation process.

Comment: In *good old* western Alchemy, there are 4 ***elements***: fire, earth, air and water. As such, *fire* is not a process (of burning). It is obscure, but the best guess I can make of it is that the translation should not be  "from" but "by".

Comment: @GyroGearloose I don't think 'by' will make sense because in other places it is mentioned Adam is created from baked clay, I'd assume the baking process involves fire.

Comment: @TruthSeeker418 as for my translation of the Bible, the word "baked" is absent, and then it could well be "sun baked", without fire.